# knockout mapping - how to remove an object from the array it belongs to?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
// viewModel
var cardViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    self.isNew = ko.observable(false);
    // etc
}
// mapping
var mapping = {
    create: function (options) {
        var innerModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {
            'cards': {
                create: function (options) {
                    //debugger;
                    return new cardViewModel(options.data);
                }
            } // etc
        });
// data
var setData = dataservice.getSet();
var observableData = ko.mapping.fromJS(setData, mapping);
```

Within my viewModel, I'd like to add something like this:

```
self.save = function() {
    var card = new cardViewModel(dataservice.save(this)) // works fine
    innerModel.cards.push(card) // doesn't work because I don't have access to innerModel from the card viewModel
}
```

Right now I'm just triggering events from the viewModels and listening to them from the innerModel, but this is getting a little messy and want to see if there's any way to access innerModel.sets() from the setViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would've organised it a little differently - does this do what you want?

```
var cardViewModel = function (data) {
    // ...
},

cardMapping = {
    create: function(options) {
        return new cardViewModel(options.data);
    }
},

viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    var setData = dataservice.getSet();
    self.cards = ko.mapping.fromJS(setData, cardMapping);

    self.save = function() {
        var card = new cardViewModel(dataservice.save(this));
        self.cards.push(card);
    };
};

$(function () {
    var vm = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

I wasn't sure which viewmodel you were trying to put your save function on - I put it on the root viewmodel.